# What security assurances does a developer running a Windows EC2 hosted Web application need?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, web-hosting, windows-server-2012

Being a developer, security is a completely new world for me! I have a windows EC2 instance running Windows server 2012 RTM, public facing .NET 4.5 Web application and SQL server 2012 web edition.

I've opened a port for FTPS & HTTP but mostly my firewall is on default settings.

- Do I need anti-virus running? (Which?)
- Do I need anti-spamwhere running? (When I use the browser to download
  Apps etc)  (Which?)
- Do I need any malicious prevention services? (Which?)
- Do I need any port-scan, security checking software to check for weak
  exposures?  (Which?)
- What do I need that I don't know I need?
- Do I need to prevent Denial of serices attacks myself?

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

Yes you should have an anti-virus.  MSE should be good enough. Just don't use the server for non-server related uses.

I would only use Chrome.  Only use to to download verified apps.

Always have the firewall on and only needed ports open.

It's nice to use nmap from another host to test for open ports.  Google nmap.  I use a home Ubuntu box/vm for such purposes.

You need to make sure you're always up to date with Windows Update.  And rebooted if needed.

If you're using Remote Desktop and don't have a VPN to your system - change to non-standard ports.  FTP should not be on a standard port 21 open publicly.  My opinion, security in obscurity can in fact help.  But mostly against script kiddies/DoS attempts at standard ports. etc.

Make sure your passwords are strong.

I'm sure there's more.

Comment: Does one just leave the anti-virus running all the time? Doesn't that drain resources

Comment: unless your system is bogged down 24/7 and can't afford to run a filesystem scan once a day, then yah - you can choose how often if runs a scan.

Comment: From an Anti-Virus perspective, Microsoft Security Essentials (MSE) is not supported on Windows Server, only on client Operating Systems such as Windows XP, Windows Vista and Windows 7.

Comment: I am running MSE on Win2008 server std.